SmtpClient error de autenticación con ionos.es
Tenemos una aplicación que de la noche a la mañana ha dejado de enviar correos a través del servidor de ionos. Hace ya un tiempo cambiaron el puerto 25 por el más seguro 587, y con este código se enviaba sin problema. El código en C# utilizado es el siguiente:
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("para@prueba.es"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("desde@prueba.es");
msg.Subject = "Prueba";
msg.Body = "Prueba";

SmtpClient clienteSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.ionos.es");

clienteSmtp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(587);
clienteSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
clienteSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_Usuario, _Contraseña);

clienteSmtp.Send(msg);

El error es el siguiente

Puestos al habla con ionos aseguran y reaseguran que en sus servidores no ha cambiado nada y que aparentemente la configuración mía es correcta.
De hecho, con esa misma configuración y mediante MailKit los correos llegan correctamente.
Además, como añadido, el error había estado siendo aleatorio durante toda la semana y ayer era con todos los correos.
Como ya me habéis dicho en comentarios, es un código estándar que no tiene ningún misterio, y todo apunta a que es problema del servidor de correo que de alguna manera me bloquea el envío.
Antes de revisar toda la aplicación para cambiar el envío de correos, me gustaría saber si puedo mirar en algún sitio más para poder hacer que funcione la actual.
Saludos.

El codigo que mostras, es codigo standard y no hace nada raro en particular. Si estan funcionando en otro lado,  puede que el problema sea realmente de ellos. O tengas algun firewall o algun bloqueo de alguna forma. No tirar ningun error el programa? de ningun tipo???

sería de ayuda si agregas el mensaje de error que te aparece

SI no tienes en mensaje de error como tal, es dificil apoyarte, sin embargo no veo porque usar Convert.ToInt16() cuando se especifica el Puerto.

@Manny, el convert es porque realmente se pasa por parámetro ese valor, pero para el ejemplo lo he puesto directamente.

¿Has capturado la conversación entre el cliente y el servidor? ¿podrías pegarla en la pregunta (eliminando los datos sensibles)?

Ah, pues no, ¿cómo podría hacer eso? No estoy demasiado ducho en esos temas.

Ahhhh tenemos un error!!! bien.. ahora preguntale a ellos que tipo de conexion segura requieren.. si es por certificados o por que tipo....

Al final era un problema de los servidores de Ionos que ni ellos mismos tenían claro de dónde venía.
Sin hacer nada se ha solventado y el código anterior funciona correctamente. No sé qué tendría que hacer con la pregunta o si lo tiene que hacer algún moderador.
Saludos.
